# Why is counting by i not working but selecting from hdb works just fine?

Tags: kdb

I have a partitioned hdb and the following query works fine :

```
select from tableName where date within(.z.d-8;.z.d)
```

but the following query breaks :

```
select count i by date from tableName where date within(.z.d-8;.z.d)
```

with the following error :

```
"./2017.10.14/:./2017.10.15/tableName. OS reports: No such file or directory"
```

Any idea why this might happen ?

Answer (score 3):

As the error indicates, there's no table called `tableName` is in a partition for 2017.10.15. For partitioned databases kdb caches table counts; it happens when it runs the first query with the following properties:

- the "select" part of the query is either `count i` or the partition field itself (in your example that would be `date`)
- the where clause is either empty or constrains the partition field only.

(`.Q.ps` -- partitioned select -- is where all this magic happens, see the definition of it if you need all the details.)

You have several options to avoid the error you're getting.

1. Amend the query to avoid having either `count i` on its own or the empty where.

Any of the following will work; the first is the simplest while the others are useful if you're writing a query for the general case and don't know field names in advance.

```
select count sym by date where date within (.z.d-8;.z.d) / any field except i
select count i by date where date within (.z.d-8;.z.d),i>=0
select `dummy, count i by date where date within (.z.d-8;.z.d)
select {count x}i by date where date within (.z.d-8;.z.d)
```

2. Use [.Q.view](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qview-subview) to define a sub-view to exclude partitions with missing tables; kdb won't cache or otherwise access them.

The previous solutions will not work if the date range in your select includes partitions with missing tables. In this case you can either

- Run [.Q.chk](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qchk-fill-hdb) to create empty tables where they are mising; or
- Run [.Q.bv](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qbv-build-vp) to construct the dictionary of table schemas for tables with missing partitions.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to create the missing tables. I  believe when doing a 'count i' on a partitioned table as you have done, it counts every single partition (not just the ones in your query) and caches these counts in .Q.pn

If you run .Q.chk[HDB root location], it should create the missing tables and your query should work

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qchk-fill-hdb

Answer (score 2):

'count i' will scan each partition regardless of what is specified in the where clause. So it's likely those two partitions are incomplete.

Better to pick an actual column for things like that or else something like

`select count i>0 by date from tableName where date within(.z.d-8;.z.d)`

will prevent the scanning of all partitions.

Jason